# curly braclet in a StringTemplate

Tags: stringtemplate, stringtemplate-4

The following StringTemplate gives me an "invalid character '}'" exception because of the closing curly brace after `return null;`:

```
$StatementList:{statement | 
public T $statement$(X x) { return null; }  }$
```

I want to have an output like:

```
public T statement1(X x) {return null; }
public T statement2(X x) {return null; }
```

How can I escape this closing curly brace?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't find a way of escaping characters, but I did manage to get it to work using the unicode character for curly braces instead.

```
statementTemplate(StatementList) ::= <<
<StatementList:{statement | 
public T <statement>(X x) <\u007B> return null; <\u007D> }>
>>
```

which produced:

```
public T statement1(X x) { return null; } 
public T statement2(X x) { return null; } 
public T statement3(X x) { return null; }
```

Comment: Nice workaround! I found another in the meantime but yours is more elegant. I added a variable $closingcurlybraclet$ at the end of the statement and defined it in my generator with template.add("closingCurlyBraclet", "}");

Answer (score 0):

Backslash (`\`) worked for me:

```
$StatementList:{statement | 
public T $statement$(X x) { return null; \}  }$
```

It seems it is not necessary to escape the opening curly bracket.